# Toggle arrows at the end of the first line of text

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, expand

How to add arrows at the end of the first line text? And I want it point down when collapse and point up when expand. Like shown as images below. Appreciate your help, thanks!

[image]

[image]

```js
$(".expander").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("expander")) {
        $(this).removeClass("expander");
    }
    else {
         $(this).addClass("expander");
    }
});
```

```css
.expander {
    height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expander">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
```

Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972728/how-do-you-show-just-the-first-line-of-text-of-a-div-and-expand-on-click)

Comment: Just FYI you can simplify that `click` handler to a single line: `$(this).toggleClass("expander")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```js
$(".expander").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("expander")) {
    $(this).removeClass("expander");
    $(".panel").addClass("open");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("expander");
    $(".panel").removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.panel {
  position: relative;
}

.expander {
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.panel:after {
  content: "V";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.panel.open:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="expander">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<details>.` tag. The  tag specifies additional details that the user can view or hide on demand.

```css
details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: #fff;
  color: green;
  font-size: 200%;
  float: right;
 
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary> Contrary to popular belief , Lorem Ipsum is not..</summary>
  
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.  </p>
</details>
```

Comment: I saw this code online, but is it possible to change the arrow position by using `detail`?

Comment: we can change the position from let to right not sure we can move the expand icon to bottom on expand. It is  possible to change color of icon or replace by a background image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo element to create the arrow and change it according to the class `expander`

**See code snippet:**

```js
$(".expander").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("expander")) {
    $(this).removeClass("expander");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("expander");
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.expander {
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 15px;
}

.expander::after {
  top: 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expander">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32.
</div>
```